# CSS: Getting the footer to stick to the bottom of a page

Tags: html, css

Some of you guys are going to immediately draw up Ryan Fait's sticky footer, but that's the one I've been using, and it has not been working out properly.

Zooming the page in and out "unsticks" the footer. Here's a live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/C2u3C/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Andrew Louis</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="about-me.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/jqueryscript.js"></script>

<body>
    <br>
    <h2>Andrew Louis</h2>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="subtitle">
            About Me 
            <div class = "subtitle-text">
            <br> <!--Spacing between image and subtitle -->
            <img align="center" src="images/Profile.jpg" /><br><br>
            <p>Synth sriracha wes anderson blog etsy, pickled truffaut street art. Brooklyn wolf sriracha trust fund fap. Retro chillwave readymade master cleanse. Mixtape carles pop-up ennui, viral DIY freegan fingerstache post-ironic williamsburg organic hella single-origin coffee lomo you probably haven't heard of them. Pickled biodiesel vinyl flexitarian narwhal occupy fanny pack, butcher forage lo-fi marfa iphone wayfarers. Gastropub aesthetic brooklyn, mcsweeney's carles wayfarers pop-up viral wolf thundercats. Put a bird on it brunch direct trade dreamcatcher kale chips, before they sold out pour-over tofu chillwave fixie 8-bit flexitarian typewriter.</p>


            <br><p> Words and stuff </p> 

            <br>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright © 2012 Andrew Louis</p>
    </div>
</body>
</head>
```

CSS:

```
/*The New Stuff Begins Here*/

* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -100px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    clear:both;
    height: 100px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
.footer{
    font-family: 'Lobster1.3Regular';
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    background:#D04D21;
}
/*

Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
http://ryanfait.com/

*/

h2{
    font-family:'WindsongRegular';
    font-size:33px;
    color:#D04D21;
    text-align:center;
}

.subtitle{
    float:left;
    width:700px;
    font-family:'Lobster1.3Regular';
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:#D04D21;
    position: absolute;
    font-size:60px;
    top: 4%;
    left: 0px;
    height: 1px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:150px;
    margin-right:50px;  
}

.subtitle-text p{
    text-align:left;
}

.subtitle-text{
    border-right:2px solid;
    padding-right:55px;
    float:left;
    border-right:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    width:700px;
    font-family:'MuseoSlab500Regular';
    text-align:center;
    /*margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;*/
    font-size:20px; 
    color:#D04D21;
}
.subtitle-text img{
    padding:3px;
    border-top: 3px dashed #D04D21;/*#000000;*/
    border-bottom:3px dashed #D04D21;/*#000000;*/
    border-left:3px dashed #D04D21;/*#000000;*/
    border-right:3px dashed #D04D21;/*#000000;*/
</html>
```

Comment: "Zooming the page in and out "unsticks" the footer" - in which browser(s)?

Comment: I was playing with footers and finally ended up in using <table> as an object between the my header and footer. You can take a look at what I have at http://www.cdsan.com. All other variants that I tried  either demonstrated magic behavior or were not working is some of the browsers.

Comment: Josh try zooming in and then scrolling down? It happens even if I do it in the tese case, I'm not sure why you guys are not seeing it. I'm seeing it on every browser, IE9, Firefox and Chrome

Comment: @KirillKobelev Is that the correct link? I'm not seeing anything about footers there

Comment: @arttronics Did you try zooming in? Also, you'll see that the footer overlaps the content which is another secondary issue...

Comment: The site itself is not about CSS. It is just an example of a page that has footer, that is adjusted to the bottom if the amount of data on the page is small. I just tried zooming in IE. Seems to work fine.

Comment: @KirillKobelev I finally got it to happen. You need to zoom in several times for it to occur.

Comment: @JoshMein, do you mean that footer does not stick to the bottom of the screen when page is scrolled to its bottom? I see a problem in the horz direction there. But in vertical it seems to be ok.

Comment: @KirillKobelev The footer is not sticking to the bottom in Chrome when you zoom in alot. I zoomed in so that the font was like 50px+ and the problem appears.

Comment: @JoshMein, I just tried it in Chrome also. Seems to work. I am not sure this is interesting to everybody (except maybe for the result). If you have a minute, I will be happy to discuss this in chat.

Comment: @KirillKobelev The cause is the `position:absolute;` and `float:left;` in his subtitle class.

Comment: **FYI:** To recreate this issue, have Developer Tools **on** and once you see the scrollbars for the `jsFiddle HTML Panel` then scroll down to see that the footer scrolls. It's just a coincidence that doing an immediate Browser Zoom reveals this glitch.

Comment: Actually the cause was the `position:absolute;` and `float:left;` in  your subtitle class. Check out my answer for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause is the `position:absolute;` and `float:left;` in your subtitle class. Once the absolute positioning is removed and you clear the float the problem goes away. Depending on where exactly you want the subtitle to show up, there should be other options available.

**CSS**:

```
.subtitle{
    float:left;
    width:700px;
    font-family:'Lobster1.3Regular';
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:#D04D21;
    text-align:left;
}

.footer, .push {
    clear:both;
    height: 100px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C2u3C/7/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C2u3C/2/

Comment: It covers the content if you set it as fixed.

Comment: @JoshMein Yeah, I think I misunderstood the question, it seems the OP was looking for a different effect.